# GameKit leaderboard GKScore initWithCategory - What to specify for "category"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

I'm trying to set up a leaderboard for my game, yet I don't know what to pass in to GKScore:initWithCategory. Looking in Itunes Connect there is "Leaderboard Reference Name" and "Leaderboard ID" both of which I have tried yet the scores still do now show up in gamecenter.

There is no mention of "category" to be found in ITC, has the terminology changed? What do I pass in to this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you need to pass is labeled as **Leaderboard ID** in the iTunes Connect leaderboard section.

Update:
I submit high scores to a leaderboard using the following, where category is the **LeaderBoard ID** as specified in iTunes Connect

```
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"yourLeaderBoardId"] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = score;

    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
    {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // handle the reporting error
            NSLog(@"error reporting score");
        }
    }];
```

Also, it seems that in the sandbox, unless two or more distinct GameCenter accounts have submitted a score, no scores will show up.